# using nlohmann::json with cppyy?

Tags: python, c++17, typeconverter, nlohmann-json, cppyy

Is it possible to pass a python `dict` into a function expecting a `nlohmann::json` ([nlohmann/json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json)) object via `cppyy`? This question *has to have* come up by now, but I wasn't able to find anything on it.

Minimal example to reproduce (without regard to performance/safety, pls forgive):

`test-json.h`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

using nlohmann::json;

void print_name_and_age(json j) {
    std::cout << j["name"] << "\n"
              << j["age"] << "\n";
}
```

`test-cppyy.py`

```py
import cppyy
cppyy.include('test-json.h')

from cppyy.gbl import print_name_and_age

some_dict = {
    "name": "alfred",
    "age": 25
}

print_name_and_age(some_dict)
```

runs into

```
    print_name_and_age(some_dict)
NotImplementedError: void ::print_name_and_age(nlohmann::json j) =>
    NotImplementedError: could not convert argument 1 (this method cannot (yet) be called)
```

I would like to be able to pass a python dict into the C++ function, and receive it as a `nlohmann::json` object. I presume I would need to write some custom converter for this?

**Design requirement/background (optional)**

I have a reinforcement learning environment class (written in C++) that needs to accept some configuration to initialize it (in its constructor). Everything's all fine passing a `nlohmann::json` object into the constructor while in the C++ domain, but I have a Python wrapper around the class too, written with `cppyy` that provides similar functionality to the C++ interface.
Uptill now, because of the aforementioned issue, I've been forced to receive a `const std::map<std::string, float>&` in the constructor instead of a `nlohmann::json`, which is what a python `dict` containing only `str -> float` mappings easily gets converted to by `cppyy`. But this obviously limits my input json files to only contain `float`s as values (my usecase requires having `strings` as keys but `string`s, `int`s, `float`s and `bool`s as values in the JSON file). I can *ofcourse* write some pre-processing code to encode my heterogenous python `dict` into a homogenous `str->float` mapping on the python front (and do the same for C++) but I'd like a cleaner solution, if possible.

Could anyone please help me achieve passing a python `dict` into the `cppyy`-imported C++ function and have it converted into a `nlohmann::json` object in the C++ function? If this requires forking `cppyy` to add extra converter code/too much trouble I presume I would need to use a `std::map<std::string, std::any / variant>` alternative? I haven't worked alot with `std::any/variant`, would like to ask if this would even be possible - python `dict` to `map<string, any>` - if this is the best alternative to a custom converter - `in terms of performance` / clean elegant code.

**Environment:**

Python 3.9.13

C++17 ( I believe `cppyy-2.4.0` doesn't support `C++20` yet, I don't have any constraint on the C++ standard)

```
cppyy==2.3.1
cppyy-backend==1.14.8
cppyy-cling==6.25.3
cppyythonizations==1.2.1
```

MacOS Monterey, Apple M1

Comment: @Wim Lavrijsen? any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered at [GitHub: Conversion from python `dict` into `nlohmann::json`](https://github.com/wlav/cppyy/issues/96#issuecomment-1251455551)

Comment: Though links to external resources are allowed, your answer should contain the answer itself. So, if the link will be outdated, your answer still will be helpful.